# Добавление текстуры на иконку, добавленную с помощью MaterialDesignThemes

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

Есть возможность с помощью `<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AddBox"/>` добавлять подобные иконки:

[image: Пример]

Однако, как можно заметить, они белые. Задача состоит в том, что бы на них "натянуть" подобную текстуру текстуру (Можно реализовать подобное просто с помощью 2х прямоугольников, текстура не имеет значения):

[image: пример текстуры]

Как реализовать подобное?

Comment: Там иконки по сути шрифты векторные, нормальным образом не натянуть текстуру если я не ошибаюсь, да и это идет в разрез с идеалогией материала

Comment: Это да, но я думаю, что можно как-то сделать подобное через маски прозрачно, может быть? С идеологией - это да, но уже просто интересно, как такое можно реализовать